# how to enable gcc to vectorize this loop

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization, eigen

I have this loop where  `b2` is a `float`, `x1` is a (Eigen c++) vector of `float`, `a1` and `a0` are `int`.

```
for(int i=1;i<9;i++)
    b2+=a0*(float)0.5*(std::log(fabs(x1(a1+a0*(i-1))))+std::log(fabs(x1(a1+a0*i))));
```

GCC returns:

```
analyze_innermost: failed: evolution of base is not affine.
```

I was wondering if there was a simple way to rewrite the loop to allow GCC to vectorize it (I'm compiling with all the unsafe options enabled...I'm doing this to learn).

## Edit:

x1 is an eigen construct. I'm using GCC 4.8.1 with O3 flag.

Comment: Is `x1` a standard (STL) vector? Did you overload `operator()` or something?

Comment: Have you tried storing the RHS of the `+=` operator in a temporary array and using a second loop to sum them up?

Comment: @OMGtechy Not duplicate. Error and code are completely different

Comment: What type is `x1`? Apart from that it looks like using Eigen (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org) could be interesting. It has vectorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break this up into 3 loops:

```
float t1[9];
float t2[9];

for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)                // (1) - gather input terms
    t1[i] = x1(a1+a0*i);

for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i)                // (2) - do expensive log/fabs operations
    t2[i] = std::log(fabs(t1[i]));     //       with minimum redundancy

for (i = 1; i < 9; ++i)                // (3) - wrap it all up
    b2 += a0*0.5f*(t2[i-1] + t2[i]);
```

I suspect that (1) may not be vectorizable (unless you have AVX2 with gathered loads), but (2) and (3) have a reasonable chance.

Comment: thanks for this: it got vectored (as you predicted) and it helped me understand how it works. I've spent the week end vectoring all the bottlenecks in that code and they run 3+\times faster!

Comment: @user189035: excellent - thanks for following up on this and letting the community know that it was effective - that's useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Your example cannot be easily vectorized because you're not accessing the entries of x1 in a sequential manner.

With sequential access, it could be vectorized like that:

```
ArrayXf x1;
b2 = (x1.segment(i,9).abs().log() + x1.segment(j,9).abs().log()).sum() * a0;
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to access the entries of x1 sequentially, short of pre-fetching them, storing them in a vector of length 8 and summing that vector.